# What does "Points on the hyperbola is $x$ units close to one focus than the other" mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Find the equation of the hyperbola

Foci $(13,0), (-13,0)$
Points on the hyperbola are $24$ units close to one focus than the other.

I am not sure what "Points on the hyperbola are 24 units close to one focus than the other." means.

Comment: If you've copied that accurately, it's probably a typo for "closer"; that is, if you take any point $P$ on the hyperbola, and $PF_1$ and $PF_2$ represent the distances from $P$ to the two foci, then those distances differ by $24$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Can you see the foci $ (13-12= c-a=1) $ unit inside the nose? for the hyperbola:
$$ {\left(\dfrac{x}{12}\right)}^2-{\left(\dfrac{y}{5}\right)}^2=1?$$

The asymptote line is $PR$

Answer (score 0):

$c=\text{distance from focus to center}=13$

$\displaystyle a={1\over2}\text{difference of distances from foci of any point}=12$

$b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}=\sqrt{13^2-12^2}=5$